# New environment for Twilio Video using Runtime, what is the service-sid?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I'm attempting to create a new environment for my Twilio Video project, specifically to modify the `domain-suffix` and `unique-name`. What is the `service-sid`?

```
# Install the twilio-cli from https://twil.io/cli

twilio api:serverless:v1:services:environments:create \
    --service-sid ZSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    --domain-suffix stage \
    --unique-name staging
```

Referencing https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api/api/environment

Answer (score 0):

Based on the format of the SID you posted "ZS", it is a Function Service.

[Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api/api/service)

> Services are containers for your environments. You may only need one
>   Service with many environments. When you begin working on a new
>   application, you will likely want to create a new Service.